# Re-use recording object in android after stop() is called

Tags: java, android, audiorecord

I am making an app where I produce sound and record this sound, evaluate this recording and do this again until the sound is good.

The problem that I have is that it seems impossible to re-use the AudioRecord object. This recording runns in a thread. 
When the onMarkerReached event is triggered I call `myAudioRecord.stop();`
and after evaluation I start it again like this:

```
    if(recorderThread == null) {
      recorderThread = new Thread(recorder.runRecorderThread);
    }
    recorderThread.start();
```

But the recorder is only called the first time this is excecuted.

Comment: Can you show us the related code you mentioned?  Off the top of my head, may I suggest removing some of the stops here, such as checking for `==NULL` in case you are presuming something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why I could not restart the recording was becaus of an NotificationProperty.
I had a boolean "isReading" and when it was done I called:

```
public void setIsReading(boolean isReading) {
  pcs.firePropertyChange("isReading", this.isReading, isReading);
  this.isReading = isReading;
}
```

so:

```
while(isReading) {
   AudioRecord.read(..);
}
```

Because I first triggered the firePropertyChange is stopped it before it stoped reading.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're never setting `recorderThread` to `null`?